# What is altarnative of eval for strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

hi what can I use inspite of eval function for that code :

```
product_pcs          = 12;
product_code         = "lkb_12" ;
eval(product_code +"_pcs_1         = product_pcs");
alert (lkb_12_pcs_1);
```

Comment: Why do you need to assign to a variable with a dynamic name in the first place? Do you have multiple such variables?

Comment: Not making extremely poor design decisions in your software I'd say is the #1 alternative.

Comment: I am getting datas from mysql with ajax and after success I have to change some which is "0" before ajax... in a loop....

Comment: To remap property names, work with the objects you get from the DB and rename them in map calls.

Comment: @momalone In a loop? You mean like over an array?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you build an object instead

```
const products = {};

prodcuts['lkb_12'].pcs = 12;
prodcuts['lkb_12'].name = 'test';


prodcuts['lkb_13'].pcs = 14;
prodcuts['lkb_13'].name = 'test2';

// ...
``
```